# Symfony 4 Voter Annotations (@IsGranted)

Tags: php, symfony, annotations, authorization

I'm trying to use Symfony Voters and Controller Annotation to allow or restrict access to certain actions in my Symfony 4 Application.

As an example, My front-end provides the ability to delete a "Post", but only if the user has the "DELETE_POST" attribute set *for that post*.

The front end sends an HTTP "DELETE" action to my symfony endpoint, passing the id of the post in the URL (i.e. `/api/post/delete/19`).

I'm trying to use the `@IsGranted` Annotation, as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/security.html).

Here's my symfony endpoint:

```
/**
 * @Route("/delete/{id}")
 * @Method("DELETE")
 * @IsGranted("DELETE_POST", subject="post")
 */
public function deletePost($post)  {
    ... some logic to delete post
    return new Response("Deleting " . $post->getId());
}
```

Here's my Voter:

```
class PostVoter extends Voter {

    private $attributes = array(
        "VIEW_POST", "EDIT_POST", "DELETE_POST", "CREATE_POST"
    );

    protected function supports($attribute, $subject) { 
        return in_array($attribute, $this->attributes, true)  &&  $subject instanceof Post;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $subject, TokenInterface $token) {
        ... logic to figure out if user has permissions.

        return $check;

    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that my front end is simply sending the resource ID to my endpoint.  Symfony is then resolving the `@IsGranted` Annotation by calling the Voters and passing in the attribute `"DELETE_POST"` and the post id.

The problem is, $post is just a post id, not an actual Post object.  So when the Voter gets to `$subject instanceof Post` it returns `false`.

I've tried injecting `Post` into my controller method by changing the method signature to `public function deletePost(Post $post)`.  Of course this does not work, because javascript is sending an id in the URL, not a Post object.

(BTW:  I know this type of injection should work with Doctrine, but I am *not* using Doctrine).

My question is how do I get `@IsGranted` to understand that "post" should be a post object?  Is there a way to tell it to look up Post from the id passed in and evaluated based on that?  Or even defer to another controller method to determine what `subject="post"` should represent?

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @NicolasB, I've added a ParamConverter:

```
class PostConverter implements ParamConverterInterface {
    private $dao;

    public function __construct(MySqlPostDAO $dao) {
        $this->dao = $dao;
    }

    public function apply(Request $request, ParamConverter $configuration)  {
        $name = $configuration->getName();            
        $object = $this->dao->getById($request->get("id"));

        if (!$object)  {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException("Post not found!");
        }

        $request->attributes->set($name, $object);

        return true;
    }

    public function supports(ParamConverter $configuration) {
        if ($configuration->getClass() === "App\\Model\\Objects\\Post")  {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This appears to be working as expected.  I didn't even have to use the @ParamConverter annotation to make it work.  The only other change I had to make to the controller was changing the method signature of my route to `public function deletePost(Post $post)` (as I had tried previously - but now works due to my `PostConverter`).

My final two questions would be:

1. What exactly should I check for in the `supports()` method?  I'm currently just checking that the class matches.  Should I also be checking that `$configuration->getName() == "id"`, to ensure I'm working with the correct field?
2. How might I go about making it more generic?  Am I correct in assuming that anytime you inject an entity in a controller method, Symfony will call the `supports` method on everything that implements `ParamConverterInterface`?

Thanks.

Comment: `api/post/delete/19` is not a very REST endpoint. It should be `api/post/19` and you know that's a delete from the HTTP verb. You had a specifique reason why not do it like `api/post/19`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What would happen if you used Doctrine is that you'd need to type-hint your `$post` variable. After you've done that, Doctrine's [ParamConverter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter) would take care of the rest. Right now, Symfony has no idea how about how to related your `id` url placeholder to your `$post` parameter, because it doesn't know which Entity `$post` refers to. By type-hinting it with something like `public function deletePost(Post $post)` and using a ParamConverter, Symfony would know that `$post` refers to the `Post` entity with the id from the url's `id` placeholder.

From the doc:

> Normally, you'd expect a $id argument to show(). Instead, by creating a new argument ($post) and type-hinting it with the Post class (which is a Doctrine entity), the ParamConverter automatically queries for an object whose $id property matches the {id} value. It will also show a 404 page if no Post can be found.

The Voter would then also know what `$post` is and how to treat it.

---

Now since you are not using Doctrine, you don't have a ParamConverter by default, and as we just saw, this is the crucial element here. So what you're going to have to do is simply to define your own ParamConverter.

[This page](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/converters.html) of the Symfony documentation will tell you more about how to do that, especially the last section "Creating a Converter". You will have to tell it how to convert the string `"id"` into a `Post` object using your model's logic. At first, you can make it very specific to `Post` objects (and you may want to refer to that one ParamConverter explicitly in the annotation using the `converter="name"` option). Later on once you've got a working version, you can make it work more generic.